# Check which font Windows uses for a character

Tags: windows, fonts, unicode

I'd like to use the trapezoid character “⏢” (U+23E2) in a MS Word document. I'd like to use the same font that Chrome and Windows 10 use to display it but every possible candidate font I try seems not to contain this character.

## Chrome

### DevTools

When I inspect the character, eventually I get to the following CSS code: `font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Roboto, "San Francisco", "Segoe UI", sans-serif`. Now, Source Sans Pro isn't even installed on my system but when I install it, it doesn't have the character. The same goes for Roboto. San Francisco I read is used on Macs only (?). Segoe UI is installed but it doesn't display the character in Word.

### Copying

Copying to MS Word doesn't do the trick because the character is a blank box. Evidently the font name that gets copied to clipboard is Source Sans Pro because that's what gets set in Word after pasting.

## Windows 10

The character can even be displayed in Windows dialog boxes, e.g. I can paste it into Explorer address bar! Crazy, I can name a file using it but I can't get it to display in Word. I checked in the registry

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes
```

and MS Shell Dlg gets mapped to Microsoft Sans Serif, which, again, doesn't contain the character.

The system must somehow be able to display it, so it must exist in a font already installed on the system.

Please help me retain my sanity in this situation ;)

Comment: I don't have MS Word, but I tried copying your trapezoid character from my browser and pasting into WordPad and it shows the font "Segoe UI Symbol".  Do you have this font installed on your system?

Comment: Indeed I do! Thanks, that solved the problem! I didn't think of WordPad, I never use it. Though I must say, it'd still be nice to have a way to know which font your system uses in dialog boxes, but never mind. You can post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Word appears to paste whatever text is in your clipboard into whatever font is already selected in Word by default.  I tried pasting the character in WordPad (Windows accessory) and it shows the font to be "Segoe UI Symbol".